Getting the exception "This will throw an exception in the future. For now it is displayed once per type" with the sqflite package on Flutter
I'm new to Flutter and facing some difficulties.
I'm building an expense tracking app and trying to implement a database using the sqflite package. However, whenever I attempt to add a new transaction, I get the exception 'This will throw an exception in the future. For now it is displayed once per type' in the debug console, and the app freezes. Am I misusing a callback function?
The Relevant code follows:
Here is my DB definition and operations code:
class DbUtil {
  DbUtil._();
  static final DbUtil instance = DbUtil._();
  static Database? _database;

  get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;

    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  _initDatabase() async {
    return await sql.openDatabase(
      path.join(await sql.getDatabasesPath(), 'transactions.db'),
      version: 1,
      onCreate: _onCreate,
    );
  }

  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE transactions (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, value FLOAT, date DATE ,category TEXT)');
  }

  Future<void> insert(String table, Map<String, Object> data) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db.insert(table, data,
        conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  }
}

Next, my main.dart (I removed some code to keep it concise on what is relevant):
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Expenses',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Category>? category;

  final _baseUrl = 'https://expenses-a210d-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/';

  List<Transact> _transactions = [];

  _openTransactionFormModal(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return TransactionForm(_addTransaction);
      },
    );
  }

  _addTransaction(String title, double value, DateTime date, String category) {
    final newTransaction = Transact(
      id: Random().nextDouble().toString(),
      title: title,
      value: value,
      date: date,
      category: category,
    );
    setState(() {
      _transactions.add(newTransaction);
      _sumTotalCategory(newTransaction);
      _addToDb(newTransaction);
    });

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  _addToDb(transaction) async {
    await DbUtil.instance.insert(
      'transactions',
      {
        'id': transaction.id,
        'title': transaction.title,
        'value': transaction.value,
        'date': transaction.date,
        'category': transaction.category,
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appBar = AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Despesas Pessoais',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20 * MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          // IconButton(
          //   onPressed: () => loadTransactions(),
          //   icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          // ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => _openTransactionFormModal(context),
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ]);
    final availableHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        appBar.preferredSize.height -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            PieChartExpenses(valueSum),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Card(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 84, 90),
                elevation: 5,
                child: total_sum(valueSum: valueSum),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: availableHeight * 0.7,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TransactionList(_transactions, _removeTransaction),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => _openTransactionFormModal(context),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}


I attempted to modify the insert function based on the solution from this answer, but it didn't work.
I also tried modifying the function to close the database afterward, but that had no effect either. From what I can tell, the database isn't even being opened.
After the App freezes, I tried to restart it. The following messages came on the Debug Console:
E/flutter (11237): #24 DbUtil.insert db_util.dart:35 
E/flutter (11237): <asynchronous suspension> 
E/flutter (11237): #25 _MyHomePageState._addToDb main.dart:109 
E/flutter (11237): <asynchronous suspension>

The line 109 on the main.dart is the one containing "transactions", (third line on the _addToDB function).
The line 35 in db_util.dart is the one that reads await db.insert(table, data, on the insert function.

Does it give any other information about what "this" is?

Nothing. As far as I can tell, maybe something asynchronous is awaiting an answer and not getting one. There is no information on the Debug Console. The only thing happening is the app freezing when I add the transaction.

After the App freezes, i tried to restart it. The following messages came on the Debug Console:
E/flutter (11237): #24     DbUtil.insert
db_util.dart:35
E/flutter (11237): 
E/flutter (11237): #25     _MyHomePageState._addToDb
main.dart:109
E/flutter (11237): 

Could you post the complete error? Edit it into your question. And which is line 109 of main.dart?

That text is all, and it only appears when I forcefully stop the app, and it doesn't show up at any other time.

It feels like a deadlock. Is the database doing anything else? Would you post a link to the docs for Transact? Try sprinkling some debug statements to narrow down exactly where the code is hanging.

Got it! Your suggestion helped me figure it out. The issue was with the _addToDb() function. It seems the database doesn't accept the DateTime type, so I had to convert it by adding .toString(). The line 'date': transaction.date was changed to 'date': transaction.date.toString(), and everything worked perfectly. Schwern, thank you for your time and suggestion. It will sound newbie(and it is), but I've never used the "Run and Debug"  on VSCode before. None the less, thank you again, Sir.

Glad I could help and that you figured it out!
